# WebGL Error: Not all control paths return a value

Tags: debugging, webgl, shader

Some of my clients are failing to initialize a webGL program. I'm catching the error with

```
gl.linkProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  throw new Error("Unable to initialize the shader program: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}
```

The log I'm getting is

```
Unable to initialize the shader program:
C:\fakepath(72,30-133): error X3507: '_directionToColor':
  Not all control paths return a value
```

I've not been able to reproduce this error on my computer. Does anyone has an idea of what is going wrong? I'm happy to share more code if that's helpful :)

Comment: Well, it looks like the shader "_directionToColor" is to blame. Line 72, if i'm not mistaken. Can you share the source code of that shader?

Comment: I'll put the code in the comprehensible way and share it, but I'm not writing `_directionToColor` anywhere and I have no idea what `_directionToColor` is about neither does google..

Comment: Search all your files for "_directionToColor". I think it's a method somewhere in your shader code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Not all control paths return a value` is an error that the compiler will throw if you're function looks like

```
if (...) {
  return ...
} else if (...) {
  return ...
}
```

Even if one of the two conditions will always be met, the compiler is not smart enough to know that and throws an error. So you have to either change `else if` to `else` or add a third return statement that, in practice, will never be used.

I've found that in some environments the shader would compile fine and that in some other (windows) it would fail.

I could not find `_directionToColor` in my code because the function name is `directionToColor` and somehow an underscore gets added.